Removing duplicates values from QGIS Attribute table
I have some fields with the same values after that I need to remove them. Some of the values are duplicates after I merged values from different layers and grouped them using the same ID number.
For example, if an attribute value is "5479-067, 5479-067" I'd need the result like "5479-067". I have not found a simple expression but it did not work for me:
array_to_string(array_distinct(string_to_array("result")))




any idea? what I did do wrong or how to solve it?
After trying the answer I need to get space between values (red line)


The expression (array_to_string(array_distinct(string_to_array("result")))) is correct, just make sure that you are using the correct delimiter. It looks like your delimiter is ', ', so try something like this: array_to_string(array_distinct(string_to_array("result", delimiter:=', ')))

It works thank you, but how I can add after "," between values like : 5372-010, 5372-013 when I tried to edit it but the results back to the doppelt one like when I try this : array_to_string(array_distinct(string_to_array("result", delimiter:=',  '))) (space after ",") ??

I am asking how I can get a space between values when I use your answer. because when I am using it I got no space between values after (,) I uploaded a pic  to understand my question.

set the delimiter to ', ', but in the array_to_string function: array_to_string(array_distinct(string_to_array("result", delimiter:=', ')), delimiter:=', ')

I see.. it worked. many thanks!

You can use the "Delete duplicates by Attribute" tool
